# How should I do with CURL in Facebook Messenger Platform(Chatbot)?

Tags: chatbot

I'm working on Facebook chatbot, and I found some difficulties while reading Facebook's official Messenger Platform tutorial. 
The frustrating part is here:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
 "setting_type":"greeting",
 "greeting":{
    "text":"Timeless apparel for the masses."
  }
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/thread_settings?access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

I'm using a Node.js and Heroku. How should I use the code above to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

If you're on OSX you can use the [terminal](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/introduction-to-the-mac-os-x-command-line) to run the command. On windows you could use [Git Bash](https://git-for-windows.github.io/).

Copy & paste your `curl` command, replace `PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN` with your token from your Facebook Developer App and run it by pressing the `enter` key.

Hope that helps.